# Do I need an specific router to create a wireless subnet?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-adapter

I am planning to extent the scope of my router by using ["AV500 Nano Powerline Adapter Starter Kit
TL-PA411KIT"](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TL-PA411KIT) plus a wireless adapter (or a wireless router such as [TP-Link TL-WR702N](http://www.tp-link.com/ar/products/details/?categoryid=3143&model=TL-WR702N) which would create another wifi access from the ethernet cable in the other part of the house.

I want to use both wifi connections at the same time and I was wondering if this router or wifi adapter should be specific or I can use any.

Would I need to create a sub net? Can any router to it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not need to create a subnet. You can if you will, but it makes your life more difficult.

The simplest solution is to add an Access Point, which will simply relay all DHCP requests to your router. This is cheap (simple component) and good, because then all of the machines in the LAN will be able to talk to each other without any problem.

You can also obtain the same configuration if you use a router with wireless capabilities instead of an AP. In this case, I suggest you turn off the DHCP server on the new router, because this will allow you once again to have a single subnet, with all machines being accessible to all machines in the LAN. This is a tad more expensive because the router is a more sophisticated component than an AP, but it allows you to configure different options in the future, should you wish to do so (the AP can only work as an AP).

Lastly, if you leave the DHCP server on in the new router, you will have a distinct subnet containing all components connected to the new router, which will be unable to communicate with the part of your LAN which is served by the first router. You can get around this limitation, but this requires more work.

Comment: Thanks! So the simple solution is an AP? Could you recommend me any AP or any brand who sells them? I've been trying to find them but I've been only finding routers like this one.

Comment: Sorry, but this site forbids discussion of brands and products, so I cannot. As for finding them, any online retail sellers will return lots of products, if you search for `access point` in Electronics or Computers.

Comment: I've found the [TL-WA7210N](http://www.tp-link.com/ar/products/details/?categoryid=&model=TL-WA701ND) and a few others but none of them seem to be cheaper than [TP-Link TL-WR702N](http://www.tp-link.com/ar/products/details/?categoryid=3143&model=TL-WR702N).
I wonder why you and other people say they are cheaper than routers.

Comment: @Alvaro Perhaps, there is a value judgement in this... If I were to offer you BMW for 100 bucks, would you buy it from me or would you suspect something?

Comment: Are you saying they are bad products? That they won't do their function unless I spend more money?

Comment: Yes. In general, it pays to pay a bit more, in order to get a higher-end product. And it pays both in terms of availability of features, and in terms of resilience and duration.

Comment: If we take the resilience and duration out of the equation, would they still do their job in the same way as the expensive ones?

Comment: In general, I prefer routers with DD-WRT pre-installed. These routers allow an enormous amount of configuration which no other router can match. However, this requires some experience. Even if you cross out these routers, not all routers are equal.

Comment: In my case, just to use it as a wireless point, I'm not looking for any other feature or configuration. I believe I will take one of the previous routers I named, as I found them cheaper yet than the access points.

Comment: Well, looking a bit more I´ve found a good solution with all included: [TL-WPA281KIT](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?categoryid=2244&model=TL-WPA281KIT). Would that do the job I'm looking for?

Comment: @Alvaro Yes it would